# Running tslint to check only typescript files

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, intellij-idea, tslint

After update to tslint 5.0.0 i tried to run the follow command:

```
tslint -c tslint.json "src\app\**\*.ts"
```

This command, in version 4.5.1, return only the problems in typescript files(.ts). But now, returns the typescript (.ts) and html(.html) files.

[image: Output from Terminal]

UPDATE 1:
My tslint.json fille (I'm using codelyzer library too, so some rules belongs to codelyzer):

```
{
"rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
],
"rules": {
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [
        true,
        "check-space"
    ],
    "curly": true,
    "eofline": true,
    "forin": true,
    "indent": [
        true,
        "spaces"
    ],
    "label-position": true,
    "max-line-length": [
        true,
        200
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
        true,
        "static-before-instance",
        "variables-before-functions"
    ],
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-bitwise": true,
    "no-console": [
        true,
        "debug",
        "info",
        "time",
        "timeEnd",
        "trace"
    ],
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-variable": true,
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-inferrable-types": true,
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": false,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "one-line": [
        true,
        "check-open-brace",
        "check-catch",
        "check-else",
        "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "quotemark": [
        true,
        "single"
    ],
    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": [
        "always"
    ],
    "triple-equals": [
        true,
        "allow-null-check"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
        true,
        {
            "call-signature": "nospace",
            "index-signature": "nospace",
            "parameter": "nospace",
            "property-declaration": "nospace",
            "variable-declaration": "nospace"
        }
    ],
    "variable-name": false,
    "whitespace": [
        true,
        "check-branch",
        "check-decl",
        "check-operator",
        "check-separator",
        "check-type"
    ],
    "directive-selector": [
        true,
        "attribute",
        "app",
        "camelCase"
    ],
    "component-selector": [
        true,
        "element",
        "app",
        "kebab-case"
    ],
    "use-input-property-decorator": true,
    "use-output-property-decorator": true,
    "use-host-property-decorator": true,
    "no-input-rename": true,
    "no-output-rename": true,
    "use-life-cycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
    "component-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-class-suffix": true,
    "no-access-missing-member": true,
    "templates-use-public": true,
    "invoke-injectable": true
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share your tslint.json?